# Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException TypeName cannot be null

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a data factory that copies data from a restful webservice into an Azure Data Warehouse. I have tested and previewed all connections and datasets.
I'm receiving the following error message.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",  
    "message":   "ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property &apos;typeName&apos; is invalid: &apos;Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: typeName&apos;.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: typeName,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",  
    "target": "ImportLegs"  
}
```

Pipeline source

```
{
    "name": "Import Trip Data",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ImportLegs",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "flightleg?StartDate=01/01/2018&EndDate=02/01/2018"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "[Trip].[Leg]"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSink",
                        "allowPolyBase": false,
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "id"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Origin"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "actualArrivalDateLocal"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Destination"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "actualArrivalDateUTC"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "FlightLogDistance"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "actualBlockTime"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "FlightLogFlightTime"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "actualDepartureDateLocal"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Aircraft"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "actualDepartureDateUTC"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "ScheduledDepartDate"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "FlightLeg",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "TripLegDW",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: Accoreding the error message "The value of the property 'typeName' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null", please recheck your  parameter setting.

Comment: any screenshot ? or any json code would be helpful.

Comment: Added pipeline source. Only seems to occur when using a restful webservice as a source.

Answer (score 2):

I also had same error and after some research i found some solution. posting to help someone further.

Error-

```
{
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedS3FileReadOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The operation on file part-00000-.csv.gz under directory test-bucket/abc_backfill/abc_visits is failed due to exception. ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.MultipartBinaryConnector,''Type=Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception,Message=Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was returned by the service.,Source=AWSSDK.Core,''Type=Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=AWSSDK.Core,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Copy data1",
"details": []
```

}

Solution - I found this is some access issue. even while testing connection it was giving success but when executing pipeline it was failing with above message. i found, i am accessing wrong dir. as above abc_backfill is root dir or shared dir that having abc_visits and it was giving issue.

I found i have another shared dir with abc_testbackfill which pointing to same abc_visits. once i changed to abc_testbackfill in dataset. it started working.
so i belive i didn't had access on abc_backfill share and i was getting error.